# https request not being sent from apache web server to tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

I have an apache web server which sends requests for a particular application to tomcat to serve them. The requests are being processed by tomcat over http, however, when using https, i get an error saying "The requested URL was not found".

Background/Architecture: 
1) Apache web server 2.4.4 is the entry point for the request. 
2) Application is deployed on tomcat 8
3) Apache web server and tomcat are connected using mod_jk / AJP13 protocol.
4) Siteminder agent is installed on web server to enable single sign on.
5) Incoming request on apache server is intercepted by siteminder which appends header information. It is then connected to tomcat which serves the request and the response is generated.
This works when the request is sent over http, however, when implementing SSL, i am unable to send request from apache server to tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason here your SSL might not be working is due to the private key is different on both the servers. Ensure that you use the same set of certificate and private key on both the server i.e on Apache and on Tomcat server

below are the commands to generate jks file using existing key and certificate
Note: **www_xyz_com.crt** will have the chain of server certificate, intermediate certificate and the root certificate

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in www_xyz_com.crt -inkey xyz.key -out xyz.pfx
```

//to create in pfx file from .crt and key file

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore xyz.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore xyz.jks -deststoretype jks
```

//to convert .pfx into .jks